# Inheriting Models from django.forms

Tags: python, django

I am linking my models to my forms by using forms.ModelForm and running the server. I get the error `"ModelForm has no model class specified"`

Here is the code I am using

```py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class meta:
        Model= User
        fields=('username' , 'email' , 'password')
```

Comment: it is `model` (with a lowercase), *not* `Model`. Furthermore it is `Meta` (with an uppercase), *not* `meta`.

Comment: Note that you will need to use `set_password` over the standard behavior of the `ModelForm` to hash the password.

Comment: Have you tried the fixed that Willem Van Onsem suggested? If so that could be posted as the answer, although that has less to do with an actual programming problem and is simply a syntactic error.

Comment: @bartcubrich: the typo's yes, but the `set_password` is an issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made some errors in your `Meta` class and `model` attribute: it is `Meta` (starting with an uppercase), and `model` (starting with a lowercase):

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username' , 'email' , 'password')
```

But that will not be sufficient. You can not set the password of the `User` model by setting the attribute. Django *hashes* the password. You should use the [**`User.set_password(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password). You can do so by overriding the `save()` method:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username' , 'email' , 'password')
```

Comment: I have done hashing of password in my views file. This is shown below                                 ```python                                                                                                                       
  if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user=user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()                                                                                                                      ```

Comment: @NishantKumar: this really looks something to do in the form. For example Django's `UserCreateForm` does this in the form as well. You can then for example use such form in a `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc. without needing to alter the predefined view logic.

Comment: thanks got my error solved actually in Model M should be in lowercase